# React: How to tell if Form is Valid/Invalid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I tell if a Form is Valid / Invalid in React?

Angular has this syntax on Formbuilders.

```
this.form.valid;
```

I am using this coding syntax. Curious if anything exists in the React library?
Currently using Material UI Library.

Right now, I am doing if else statements and error checking all 10 fields. Looking for shorthand method.

https://onestepcode.com/creating-a-material-ui-form/

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center" direction="column">
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            id="name-input"
            name="name"
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            value={formValues.name}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            id="age-input"
            name="age"
            label="Age"
            type="number"
            value={formValues.age}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a library called [Formik](https://formik.org/). It takes a bit of time to learn, but it's a really powerful library, and I use it all the time now (with MUI).

Comment: is there anything in the native react library however? will take a look then, thanks

Comment: react doesn't usually build in features like that itself, it's just the core functionality.

Comment: ok, please add last comment into answer, thanks !

Comment: also, feel free to upvote question, thanks

Answer (score 4):

To tell if a form content is valid or not - regardless the framework - you can simply use the following:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formElement = e.target;
    const isValid = formElement.checkValidity();
    
    // add more logic here
  }

...

    <form
      action={action}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      className={style.form}
    >
      <input type='email' name='email' />
      <input type='number' name='age' required />
    </form>
```

This will use the built-in validation function and will return true if the email is correct and the age is provided.

Please note that email is not 'required', i.e. an empty value is considered correct.

I just wrote an article where I discuss exactly this: form validation/submission using built-in validation API.
No need to install any package!

https://medium.com/p/491327f985d0

Comment: This is very clean and cool solution. I have not used it for very complex types of form but for simple forms where the required or error props are in, it works nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your problem, you want to validate the form, which can be done by checking if the states are valid or not.

```
function handleSubmit(e) {  
    e.preventDefault(); // to stop the form submission refresh the page

    // now you can check the the validation part

    // here are some sample validation that will check if the username has 5 

    // characters or not and checks if the age is greater than 18 or not.

    // validations
 
    if (formValues.name.length < 5) return; 
    if (formValues.age < 18) return;

    // if the code reaches this point then it is valid form 
sendToDb(); 
    // similar more functions or statements can be called
}
```

By checking the state value in the submission of the form it can be validated.

The above mentioned way is the manual way but if you want to validate it using a single line validation by using some third party library, then this is the solution that i would likely go with.

I found this package in [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-input-validator) it works fine. This is how you can use it.

**1. Install the package.**

```
npm install react-native-input-validator
```

**2. Usage:**

```
import TextInput from "react-native-input-validator";

<TextInput type="email"  ref={someReference}/>

// check the value is valid or not in the submission of the form by using 

//[reference].isValid() method


someReference.isValid();
```

Hope it helps thank you.

for more reference check the package and see the use in more details in the examples.

**package :** https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-input-validator

Comment: yeah, was hoping there a single line check, instead of doing if-then for all 10 of my form fields

Comment: @mattsmith5 check out the new edit i hope it helps.